# import android.widget.Button Unused import directive

Tags: android, android-studio, importerror

```
package com.example.app1

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.widget.Button

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private Button button;

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

I try to resolve this issues but I can not solve it

I set up an auto-import setting in android studio but this problem not resolved

I am a beginner in the android studio please help me

advance thanks for your help .

Comment: @Pandeeshwaran You're mixing up two languages. Your file is of Kotlin while the variable declaration is of Java. `val button: Button` is what you need. Also try to be more precise and specific about the issue, in your question henceforth.

Comment: thanks, sir it's my mistake I change to java my problem was solved